# Which version of IMalloc should I use in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, shell, types, delphi-xe

I'm trying to refactor a Delphi 5 project in Delphi XE, to do that I need to fix some errors in a unit called BrowseDr. The error I'm getting is

```
[DCC Error] BrowseDr.pas(1033): E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters
 must be identical

line 1033:   SHGetMalloc(FShellMalloc);
```

"MyShlObj":

```
//SHGetMalloc declaration 
function SHGetMalloc(var ppMalloc: IMalloc): HResult; stdcall;
```

Now the IMalloc used in the declaration of FShellMalloc is derived from a `OLE2.IMalloc` 
while the one used in "MyShlObj" is from `ActiveX.IMalloc`.

Is it possible alter one of them? 
If yes, is it recommended?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `OLE2` unit was used by older Delphi versions, this unit was replaced by the `ActiveX` unit, so now you must use the  `ActiveX` types in your new project.

Comment: Okey, thanks now i know where to change at least, just have to figure out how.

Comment: For anybody who gets this in the future:  Always specify the unit name prefix (OLE2.x or ActiveX.x) explicitly to resolve "Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical".

Comment: Note: You can explicitly qualify the type (ActiveX.IMalloc) or make sure that the ActiveX unit is first in the uses clause, but as that latter solution is fragile, I recommend explicitly qualifying it.

Answer (score 1):

The only alteration I think will work is to make sure that FShellMalloc is derived from the same interface as the one used from MyShlObj.

Modify either one to use the same IMalloc as the other.

Comment: Yes, thats what i thought but how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Check your uses clause.  A lot of third party code uses compiler directives to load the correct unit.  Changing Compiler version will often result in the wrong file being loaded.

`DFS` is a classic example. Go to `DFS.INC` and ensure an appropriate `DFS_COMPILER_xxx` is defined.